# Pass decision_factor instead of contamination factor in sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I've been looking through sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor documentation for a way to pass a decision_factor (e.g. 1.25) to use in outlier vs inlier classification instead of a contamination rate. In most real-life examples the contamination rate is not known beforehand, so this model is not usable.

From what I can tell, there's no way to do this right now. What is the best way to submit a feature request?

Comment: If you want to know how to submit a feature request to a project, you should probably refer to that project guidelines. I think this kind of question is considered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I don't know what's the best way to submit a feature request, but you are probably looking for this:

```
clf = neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20)

decision_factor = clf.fit(X).negative_outlier_factor_
```